# How to pass an argument to supervisord in docker?

Tags: docker, supervisord

I am running two python services inside docker. Both services require a common argument, which I provide during "docker run"

Currently, I am achieving this by calling both the services from a shell script. But, I think the proper solution would be using supervisor inside docker and run both the services through it.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
[program:A]
command=python -m A.py <argument>

[program:B]
command=python -m B.py <argument>
```

The dockerfile looks like this:

```
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

How can I pass the argument to supervisor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use an environment variable: from [supervisor doc](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#environment-variables)

> Environment variables that are present in the environment at the time that `supervisord` is started can be used in the configuration file using the Python string expression syntax `%(ENV_X)s`:

```
[program:example]
command=/usr/bin/example --loglevel=%(ENV_LOGLEVEL)s
```

> In the example above, the expression `%(ENV_LOGLEVEL)s` would be expanded to the value of the environment variable `LOGLEVEL`.

In your case, your common argument could be set in an environment variable passed to the container with a `docker run -d -e "COMMON_ARG=myarg"`.